# "Successfully saved!" pop-up after submit ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, submit

If some inserts a new customer/category etc I want some kind of pup-up screen that says: "Successfully saved". I know there is: `OnClientClick="return confirm (text)"` but this not exactly where I am looking for.

**My code:**

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dbconn As SqlConnection
    Dim dbcomm As SqlCommand
    Dim strsql, Categorie, Klant, Website, Titel, Naslag As String

    Categorie = DropDownCat.SelectedValue.ToString
    Klant = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString
    Website = TextBoxWebsite.Text
    Titel = TextBoxTitel.Text
    Naslag = TextBoxslag.Text

    dbconn = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("sqlString"))
    dbconn.Open()

    strsql = "INSERT INTO tbl_Project (KlantID, Titel, Naslag, Website, CatID) VALUES ('" + Klant + "','" + Titel + "','" + Naslag + "','" + Website + "','" + Categorie + "')"
    dbcomm = New SqlCommand(strsql, dbconn)
    dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()

    dbconn.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some javascript to the page after your insert.

This will show a simple Javascript alert when the page has finished loading.

Something like this:

```
Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "thanks", "alert('Thank you for inserting bla bla');", True)
```

You could wrap your insert in a `try catch` block and spit out a different message based on the result too.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark as answered if it works for you. Helps other visitors find the answer too :)

Comment: Yes I will, have to wait a few minutes ;)